# Rolling Calculations in R, quarterly data but the rolling should be on annual basis, cumprod

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
PERIOD    GROWTH    PRICE
2011K1    0.88    0.88
2011K2    0.93    0.93
2011K3    0.96    0.96
2011K4    0.98    0.98
2012K1    1.13
2012K2    1.16
2012K3    1.12
2012K4    1.17
2013K1    1.07
2013K2    1.11
2013K3    1.03
2013K4    1.03

In 2011 PRICE = GROWTH
In 2012K1 PRICE = GROWTH[2012K1]*avg(PRICE in 2011)
In 2012K2 PRICE = GROWTH[2012K2]*avg(PRICE in 2011)
In 2012K3 PRICE = GROWTH[2012K3]*avg(PRICE in 2011)
In 2012K4 PRICE = GROWTH[2012K4]*avg(PRICE in 2011)
In 2013K1 PRICE = GROWTH[2013K1]*avg(PRICE in 2012)
In 2013K2 PRICE = GROWTH[2013K2]*avg(PRICE in 2012)
In 2013K3 PRICE = GROWTH[2013K3]*avg(PRICE in 2012)
In 2013K4 PRICE = GROWTH[2013K4]*avg(PRICE in 2012)
```

...

In each quarter the average price from the previous quarter is used to multiply GROWTH in that particular quarter, i.e. each quarter within the same year is multiplied by the same average price, which is the average price in the year before.

I tried using cumprod() but failed to make it roll annually when my data is quarterly. I can do for-loop, the problem is I have to do this for thousands to products.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data in the Note at the end compute the quarters, `qtr` and then loop through the rows computing PRICE.  No packages are used.

```
run <- function(DF, k = 4) {
  nr <- nrow(DF)
  DF$qtr <- 1:k
  for(i in (k+1):nr) DF$PRICE[i] <- DF$GROWTH[i] * mean(DF$PRICE[i-DF$qtr[i]-(k-1):0])
  DF
}
run(DF)
```

giving:

```
   PERIOD GROWTH    PRICE qtr
1  2011K1   0.88 0.880000   1
2  2011K2   0.93 0.930000   2
3  2011K3   0.96 0.960000   3
4  2011K4   0.98 0.980000   4
5  2012K1   1.13 1.059375   1
6  2012K2   1.16 1.087500   2
7  2012K3   1.12 1.050000   3
8  2012K4   1.17 1.096875   4
9  2013K1   1.07 1.148578   1
10 2013K2   1.11 1.191516   2
11 2013K3   1.03 1.105641   3
12 2013K4   1.03 1.105641   4
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "PERIOD    GROWTH    PRICE
2011K1    0.88    0.88
2011K2    0.93    0.93
2011K3    0.96    0.96
2011K4    0.98    0.98
2012K1    1.13
2012K2    1.16
2012K3    1.12
2012K4    1.17
2013K1    1.07
2013K2    1.11
2013K3    1.03
2013K4    1.03"
DF.orig <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Grothendieck, thanks for your answer, your program does the job, can you generalize it, I mean here we have a short sample, I have thousands of products, my data is in long format, I would like to use your code in a group_by statement and pass it to dplyr's mutate.

Comment: Have turned it into a function.

Comment: I edited DF.original to include a grouping variable PRODUCT and stack them on top of each other, I was wondering how I can use your function together with group_by(PRODUCT) %>% mutate(PRICE = fun(),...)

Comment: Please do not change the problem after it has already been answered. Using the original data we can add a `PRODUCT` column like this `DF$PRODUCT <- 1` and then `DF %>% group_by(PRODUCT) %>% do(run(.)) %>% ungroup`  Although this only shows it for one product it would be the same for many.  The key point is that dot normally refers to the entire data frame, even within a `group_by`, but within a `do` dot refers to just the rows of the data frame in the current group.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I came a long way because of your answer, I understand your point about not changing the problem, I do not know how I can undo that, it is up to the reviewers now.

Answer (score 0):

-- Update: Realized this answer produces incorrect result -- @Rebecca

Another option :)

```
# I'll use tidyverse for this approach.
library(tidyverse)

# First, I'll generate a dataset similar to yours.
data <- tibble(year = rep(2011:2013, each=4),
               quarter = rep(1:4, times=3),
               growth_quarter = c(0.88,
                          0.93,
                          0.96,
                          0.98,
                          1.13,
                          1.16,
                          1.12,
                          1.17,
                          1.07,
                          1.11,
                          1.03,
                          1.03))

# Create a new tibble with desired output.
data_m <- data %>%

  # Find the average growth per year.
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(growth_annual = mean(growth_quarter)) %>%

  # Remove grouping by year for next calculations.
  ungroup() %>%

  # Organize by year and quarter to ensure consistent results for calculation in next step.
  arrange(year, quarter) %>%

  # Multiply current quarter's growth by last year's average growth.
  mutate(growth_quarter*lag(growth_annual))
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I like your approach, I prefer going the tidyverse way as I have thousands of products, my data is in long format. Your program is not doing what I intended, the growth rate in the current year has to be multiplied by the average PRICE from the previous year, not the average growth rate.

Comment: The value in the 6th row should be 1.16 * ( 0.88 +0.93+ 0.96+ 0.98)/4 = 1.0875 but it is not.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I've played around with it for a bit, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this without a for loop - the calculation builds on itself. If anyone else has an idea, I'm all ears, though.